# http.client.HTTPResponseオブジェクトはどのような構造でしょうか？

Tags: python3

urllib.requestモジュールのurlopen関数を使用し得られるhttp.client.HTTPResponseオブジェクトの構造について、以下の点をお教えいただけないでしょうか？
・ボディデータにはどのようなデータが含まれているのか（htmlファイルの中身でしょうか？）
・ボディデータ以外にはどのようなデータが含まれているのか

初歩的な質問で申し訳ありませんが、お教えください。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ボディデータにはどのようなデータが含まれているのか

HTMLを返すresponse(Content-type: text/html)なら、bodyにはHTML本文が入っているでしょう。他のContent-type(image, pdf, cssなど)ならばHTMLではないでしょう。

> ボディデータ以外にはどのようなデータが含まれているのか

http.client HTTPResponse Objects - Python3
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/http.client.html#httpresponse-objects

ここに書いてありますが、body以外にもheaderやstatus codeの情報が含まれています。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ボディデータに含まれるデータはcontent-typeによって異なるとのこと、理解できました。またボディデータ以外につきましても、いただいたURLを確認し理解できました。